# How can I make scripts work on elements divided by if-else in Laravel Blade

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a page, divided on 3 steps using Laravel's @if @else operators (@if ($step == 1) html_code @else html_code). Each step shows independently by using Livewire. One of this steps uses self-maded tabs maded with JQuery. Blade of one step looks like this:

```
<div class="tabs-b">
                        <div class="tabs-b__btns">
                            <div class="tabs-b__btn tabs-b__btn_active js--tab-btn" wire:click="deliveryConditionClick">
                                Фиксированная закупочная стоимость
                            </div>
                            <div class="tabs-b__btn js--tab-btn" wire:click="deliveryConditionClick">
                                Рассчитывать от&nbsp;объема закупки
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tabs-b__tabs-wrapper">
                            <div class="tabs-b__tab">
                                <div class="input-b">
                                    <input type="text" class="input input-b__input js--hint-input js--num-mask" placeholder="Кол-во грамм за цену">
                                    <label class="input-b__label">Минимальная сумма заказа у поставщика на все товары</label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- input-b -->

                                <div class="input-b">
                                    <input type="text" class="input input-b__input js--hint-input js--num-mask" placeholder="Закупочная стоимость 1шт товара">
                                    <label class="input-b__label">Закупочная стоимость 1шт товара</label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- input-b -->

                                <div class="input-b">
                                    <div class="input-b__text">Позже при создании закупки на основании этих полей будет автоматически рассчитана цена для покупателя с учетом накрутки 16%. Из которых 4% – комиссия Баобум, 12% – вознаграждение организатора закупки.</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- input-b -->

                            </div>

                            <div class="tabs-b__tab" style="display: none">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-bordered-block">
                                        <div class="input-b input-b_duble">
                                            <div class="input-b__inner-wp input-b__inner-wp_long">
                                                <input type="text" class="input input-b__input js--hint-input" placeholder="Объем закупки (руб.)" value="10 000">
                                                <label class="input-b__label">Объем закупки (руб.)</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-b__inner-wp">
                                                <input type="text" class="input input-b__input js--hint-input" placeholder="Шт. в закупке" value="10">
                                                <label class="input-b__label">Шт. в закупке</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-b-desc input-b-desc_black">Итого: 575 руб. за шт при сборе заказов на 11 500 руб.</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- form-bordered-block -->

                                    <div class="form-bordered-block">
                                        <div class="input-b input-b_duble">
                                            <div class="input-b__inner-wp input-b__inner-wp_long">
                                                <input type="text" class="input input-b__input js--hint-input" placeholder="Объем закупки (руб.)">
                                                <label class="input-b__label">Объем закупки (руб.)</label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="input-b__inner-wp">

                                                <input type="text" class="input input-b__input js--hint-input" placeholder="Шт. в закупке">
                                                <label class="input-b__label">Шт. в закупке</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- input-b -->

                                        <div class="input-b-desc">При заполнении полей будет рассчитана ваша цена</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- form-bordered-block -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="add-btn">
                                    <div class="add-btn__ico">
                                        <svg class="icon__pluse" width="10px" height="10px">
                                            <use xlink:href="#pluse"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>Добавить условие поставки</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQuery part looks like this:

```
$('.js--tab-btn').click(function (){
            var $btn = $(this),
                $block = $btn.closest('.tabs-b'),
                index = $btn.index();

            if($btn.hasClass('tabs-b__btn_active')) return;

            $block.find('.tabs-b__btn').removeClass('tabs-b__btn_active');
            $btn.addClass('tabs-b__btn_active');

            $block.find('.tabs-b__tab').hide().eq(index).fadeIn();

        });
```

If I put HTML part to the first step - it works fine. But if I put it to the next steps - JQuery doesn't work and tabs become inactive. If I emit a custom event using Livewire - it doesn't work either. At least on the 2nd step. What should I do? How to make scripts work on steps of one blade file?

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your bundle? See if jQuery works at all.

Comment: JQuery works. But with Livewire scripts, I suppose, it starts doing apeshit.

Comment: I used buttons instead the Bootstrap tabs. Bootstrap tabs never work for me using Livewire